# Etimología de "soja"

Tags: etimología, sustantivos, japonés

Hoy me ha dado por mirar en el diccionario la etimología de *[soja](http://dle.rae.es/soja)*, y leo que es una de las palabras que nuestro idioma ha importado del japonés, concretamente de *shoyu*.

Sin embargo, me extraña que esa sílaba *yu* haya derivado en *ja*. Más cercana me resulta la palabra *soy* del inglés, que simplemente elimina la última *u* (y suaviza el sonido de la *s*).

Así pues, ¿cómo llegó *shoyu* a ser *soja*? ¿Desde cuándo se usa esta palabra en nuestro idioma?

Answer (score 5):

La tesis doctoral [*Los japonesismos de la lengua española: historia y transcripción*](https://rio.upo.es/xmlui/handle/10433/3716), de Rafael Fernández Mata, explica con profundidad lo que se conoce en relación a lo que se pide en la pregunta:

> El japonesismo «soja» proviene de la voz, con doble posibilidad gráfica, 醤油 o 
>   醬油 /**s’oH**ju/, que en japonés se define como: «tipo de condimento. Líquido de color marrón oscuro que se saca de prensar granos de soja y trigo que han sido tratados con *coyi* (un agente fermentante) y después dejado fermentar en un preparado con salmuera. 
>   Condimento característico de Japón» (*Daiyirín*). 
>          Desde los primeros registros en CORDE se muestra una clara preferencia por la forma *soja* (25 casos) frente a la grafía *soya* (5 casos). En CREA hallamos 956 muestras con *soja(s)*, frente a 573 casos de *soya(s)*. En CORPES XXI, la distancia de uso entre 
>   ambas grafías aumenta, y encontramos 1820 casos de *soja(s)*, frente a 694 de *soya(s)*. 
>   En efecto, como señalan las obras lexicográficas españolas (DUEAE y DClave), la 
>   forma *soya* se registra principalmente en el español meridional o hispanoamericano. Si 
>   bien, en sus orígenes, el 92,85 % de los 5 casos de *soya* en CORDE pertenecen a España 
>   y el 88,34% de los 25 casos de *soja* también. En CREA la situación es distinta: el 
>   51,97% de los casos de *soja* son de Argentina, el 38,38% de España y el resto de países como Paraguay, Chile, Venezuela, Uruguay, Panamá, Cuba, etc. El 100% de *sojas* pertenecen a Argentina. Por otro lado, casi la totalidad de los casos de *soya(s)* se 
>   registran en Hispanoamérica (México, Colombia, Chile, Bolivia, Ecuador, Perú, 
>   Guatemala, Costa Rica, Panamá, etc.). En cuanto al CORPES XXI, de los 1820 casos de
>   *soja(s)*, solo 532 pertenecen a España, en torno a 920 son de Argentina, y el resto se registran en Uruguay, Paraguay, Ecuador, Cuba, Chile, Bolivia, México y Venezuela. 
>   Por lo que respecta a *soya(s)*, de los 694 casos, 215 se inventarían en México, 129 en Bolivia, 91 en Colombia y el resto en países como Chile, Cuba, Ecuador, Nicaragua, 
>   Estados Unidos, República Dominicana y Venezuela. En definitiva, *soya* se utiliza en países hispanoamericanos, mientras que *soja* se emplea principalmente en España y Argentina, además de otros países hispanoamericanos (como Paraguay, Chile, 
>   Venezuela, Uruguay, Panamá, Cuba, etc.). [...] 
>   [...]
>   
>          Poseemos varias fechas de primera documentación textual en español. En primer lugar, el DCECH sostiene su primer registro es del DRAE de 1925, como así se demuestra también por el NTLLE. Sin embargo, gracias a las muestras del CORDE, 
>   podemos adelantar su primera documentación escrita al periodo comprendido entre 1793 y 1801, con la forma *soja*. Desde su primera documentación no observamos 
>   variación significativa o formal.
>   
>          [...] En general, 
>   observamos que las palabras de origen japonés suelen ser adoptadas en español sin 
>   cambios fonéticos sustanciales, por lo que es de esperar que en el paso de /**s’oH**ju/ 
>   (japonés) a /só·xa/, o con glotal sonora [ɦ] en español, exista alguna o algunas lenguas intermediarias. Según el OED, en japonés existe una forma coloquial, *soy*, procedente del acortamiento del significante /**s’oH**ju/, que fue la base para la forma holandesa, *soya*
>   o *soja*. Tanto el DCECH, como el DUEAE, concuerdan con esta versión, aunque este 
>   último cree que la forma holandesa procede del manchú *soya*, «por ser región con 
>   grandes extensiones de cultivo de soja», por lo que el préstamo no sería de origen 
>   japonés. De acuerdo con Corominas, la forma predominante en Hispanoamérica, *soya*, 
>   debe su significante a la influencia de las formas inglesas *soy*, *soya* o *soy-beans*. El LPR
>   sostiene que la voz que utilizan las lenguas europeas procede del manchú, aunque esta lengua la tomó del japonés, y que del manchú pasó a través del inglés por la influencia del alemán. Sea como fuere, a menos que se realice un estudio profundo del origen manchú para esta voz, casi todos concuerdan en que, en última instancia, la voz es japonesa, por lo que parece más plausible el origen nipón del término.

Comment: "el 92.85% de los 5 casos de *soya*"? Eso son 4.6425 casos, cómo puede ser?

Comment: Tienes razón, @wimi: yo tampoco entiendo esos porcentajes.

Comment: @wimi: Lo único que se me ocurre es que el autor quizás haya aplicado algún tipo de ponderación dependiendo de si cada caso proviene o no del mismo documento. Pero realmente no lo sé.

Comment: en la página 632 aclara que, en el CORDE, encontró "5 casos en 3 documentos" de la forma *soya*, así que eso tampoco funciona... Realmente extraño. Buen hallazgo en cualquier caso.

Comment: @wimi: Sí, eso ya lo había visto. Lo que me gustaría encontrar es una explicación sobre cómo ha calculado las frecuencias.

Answer (score 3):

La palabra viene del [dialecto Kagoshima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kagoshima_dialect#History) de japonés, pero se llegó a castellano vía neerlandés, y parece que ha adoptado la ortografía (si no la pronunciación) de esta palabra:

- 醬油 (tsjàng-yuw) `chino medio`

  - 醤油 /ʃijauju/ `japonés medio/antiguo`

    - 醤油 /ʃoju/ `japonés`
    - 醤油 /soj ~ ɕoj/ `japonés Satsuma`<sup>1 2</sup>

      - soja /ʃoja/ `neerlandés`<sup>3 4</sup>

        - soja /soxa/ `castellano`

---

1. <sup>[鹿児島県の方言ページ](https://web.archive.org/web/20180716070747/http://www6.shizuokanet.ne.jp/kirameki/hougen/kagoshima.htm)</sup>
2. <sup>https://www.jlect.com/entry/13/soi-shoi/</sup>
3. > <sup>**DCECH:** Probablemente por conducto del holandés *soja*.  En muchas partes de América dicen *soya*, modelado según el ingl. *soy* o *soya* (o *soy-beans*).</sup>
4. > <sup>**DUEAE:** **Para la forma soja:** Probablemente préstamo del holandés *soja* y éste del manchú *soya*, por ser región con grandes extensiones de cultivo de soja.</sup>

Comment: Lo curioso es que _soja_ en neerlandés se pronunciaría _soya_. ¿Será que se adoptó al castellano tomando en cuenta la grafía y no la pronunciación?

Comment: Según el [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000302.jpg), la palabra japonesa es de origen manchú.

Comment: En japonés estándar そ = /so/, ¿cómo sería en el dialecto de Satsuma?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' No en el castellano en ciertos países de América, donde *soya* es lo usual.

Comment: @c.p.: Sí, esto se explica en mi respuesta.

Comment: @pablodf76 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kagoshima_dialect#Other_changes